# Including WYSIWYG Editor in Plugin Admin Settings Page?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

How would I include a WYSIWYG editor on the admin settings page as opposed to a standard text area?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
the_editor($content, $id, $prev_id, $media_buttons, $tab_index, $extended);
```

is deprecated.

Use instead:

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );
```

More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

To include this in your Admin Settings page all you need to do is replace the input or textarea with the wp_editor() code. Example:

If you are using a class to output a custom Admin Settings page. The form field would be output like this:

```
public function content_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<textarea type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[content]" value="%s" />',
        esc_attr( $this->options['content'])
    );
}
```

Replace the function above with the following:

```
public function content_callback()
{
    printf(
        wp_editor(
           my_option_name[section_one_content], 
           $this->options['section_one_content'])
    );
}
```

You can find info on using a class to create options pages here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 0):

This is super old and possibly this function did not exist when this was posted. That said, just use this:

```
<?php the_editor($content, $id, $prev_id, $media_buttons, $tab_index); ?>
```